# Why does nginx not work when it is running?

Tags: nginx, centos, centos8

I meet a strange issue, I installed nginx via command `yum install nginx -y` on CentOS8 stream, and  I checked its status via command `sudo netstat -plutn | grep nginx`, it runs.

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9962/nginx: master
```

And the `nginx.conf` file is following

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

}
```

In folder `conf.d`, there is only one config file called `cx.conf`

```
server {
        listen 80;
        return 403;
}
```

I thought I will get 403 error if I visit this server via its IP, but actually, I got Empty reply from server.

#### What I have done

1. Checked if the ports are allowed, and yes, they are all allowed, I can get some response like this `Connection to **.***.***.*** port 80 [tcp/http] succeeded!`
2. Checked another application which is not running on nginx, and yes, there's an application which is running via Docker container on this server. I can visit it via `ip:8080`.
3. Uninstall and reinstall nginx, and yes. But it is still the same.
4. Set SELinux disabled

It seems that nginx is running, but it doesn't work. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: You haven't said what you expect it to do. What it "doesn't work" means? Based on your description, everything works fine.

Comment: @DanilaVershinin Actually, I have. Please check this line `I thought I will get 403 error if I visit this server via its IP, but actually, I got Empty reply from server.`

Comment: when you install nginx from packages, it comes with some default HTML at /usr/share/nginx/html or a similar location which has an index.html and thus will give 200.